# Remove tabs from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have pinned a few tabs in Chrome (I'm currently using the version 53.0.2785.101). Now it seems it was a mistake, because now every time I start Chrome these tabs open in it, pinned. Even if I unpin them and close them.

Is there a way to remove them permanently? Where does Chrome store information about the tabs it should open at startup? (I'm on Linux.)

Comment: Unpinning them and closing them should be enough.

Comment: Apparently it isn't.

Comment: I mean, that's the correct use - it might be syncing them down from Google if you've got Chrome Sync in your settings, set to just pull changes I suppose. I'd check there and if that's not working, nuke your profile and start a new one.